# pivot table using awk command

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to pivot a file using awk. 
Input File:

```
FA-2D_006 10000090fa180e49
FA-2D_011 10000090fa180e49
FA-3D_004 10000090fa180e49
FA-4D_005 10000090fa180e49
FA-2D_004 20010090fa180e49
FA-2D_008 20010090fa180e49
FA-3D_004 20010090fa180e49
FA-1D_006 20020090fa180e49
FA-4D_004 20020090fa180e49
FA-1D_006 20030090fa180e49
FA-4D_004 20030090fa180e49
FA-2D_006 20040090fa180e49
FA-2D_009 20040090fa180e49
FA-3D_005 20040090fa180e49
FA-1D_006 10000090fa180e48
FA-1D_011 10000090fa180e48
FA-2D_006 10000090fa180e48
FA-3D_005 10000090fa180e48
FA-4D_006 10000090fa180e48
FA-1D_004 20010090fa180e48
FA-2D_006 20010090fa180e48
FA-2D_011 20010090fa180e48
FA-3D_004 20010090fa180e48
FA-3D_006 20010090fa180e48
FA-4D_005 20010090fa180e48
FA-1D_006 20020090fa180e48
FA-2D_004 20020090fa180e48
FA-2D_010 20020090fa180e48
FA-3D_004 20020090fa180e48
FA-4D_004 20020090fa180e48
FA-3D_005 20030090fa180e48
FA-3D_007 20030090fa180e48
FA-1D_005 20040090fa180e48
```

Desired output:

```
-----------------------------
FA-1D_004   20010090fa180e48
-----------------------------
FA-1D_005   20040090fa180e48
-----------------------------
FA-1D_006   10000090fa180e48
            20020090fa180e48
            20020090fa180e49
            20030090fa180e49
-----------------------------
FA-1D_011   10000090fa180e48
-----------------------------
FA-2D_004   20020090fa180e48
            20010090fa180e49
-----------------------------
FA-2D_006   10000090fa180e48
            10000090fa180e49
            20010090fa180e48
            20040090fa180e49
-----------------------------
FA-2D_008   20010090fa180e49
-----------------------------
FA-2D_009   20040090fa180e49
-----------------------------
FA-2D_011   20010090fa180e48
-----------------------------

FA-2D_011   10000090fa180e49
            20010090fa180e48
-----------------------------
FA-3D_004   10000090fa180e49
            20010090fa180e49
            20010090fa180e48
            20020090fa180e48
-----------------------------
FA-3D_005   10000090fa180e48
            20040090fa180e49
            20030090fa180e48
-----------------------------
FA-3D_006   20010090fa180e48
-----------------------------
FA-3D_007   20030090fa180e48
-----------------------------
FA-4D_004   20020090fa180e49
            20030090fa180e49
            20020090fa180e48    
-----------------------------
FA-4D_005   10000090fa180e49
            20010090fa180e48
-----------------------------
FA-4D_006   10000090fa180e48
-----------------------------
```

Kindly let know how to create the pivot to form the desired output using awk.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please use code tags `{}` for your samples it is NOT clear from it.

Comment: Not able to relate question with o/p.

Comment: If you want someone to help you, it's generally a good idea to make it easy for them to do so. Presenting an unintelligible mess of mumbo-jumbo without explanation doesn't cut it. Please simplify your example to use short, readily distinguishable strings snd explain what processing is needed. Thank you.

Comment: asked and answered many times on this site, just do a search for it.

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter then

***Here is one-liner:***

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2; if(!(k in t)){a[$1]=($1 in a? a[$1] RS sprintf("%*s",length($1)+1,"") :"")$2; t[k]}}END{s=sprintf("%0*s\n", length(k),""); gsub(/0/,"-",s); for(i in a)print s i,a[i] }' file
```

With **GNU awk** if you add, you will get right order,

[You may try here by pasting given data, in stdin tab](http://tpcg.io/3tjps8)

```
BEGIN{
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
}
```

**Better Readable:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{
           PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
     }
     {
        k=$1 FS $2; 
        if(!(k in t))
        {
           a[$1]=($1 in a? a[$1] RS sprintf("%*s",length($1)+1,"") :"")$2; 
           t[k]
        }
     }
  END{
         s=sprintf("%0*s\n", length(k),""); 
         gsub(/0/,"-",s); 
         for(i in a)print s i,a[i] 
     }
    ' file
```

[image]
**Input:**

```
$ cat file
FA-2D_006 10000090fa180e49
FA-2D_011 10000090fa180e49
FA-3D_004 10000090fa180e49
FA-4D_005 10000090fa180e49
FA-2D_004 20010090fa180e49
FA-2D_008 20010090fa180e49
FA-3D_004 20010090fa180e49
FA-1D_006 20020090fa180e49
FA-4D_004 20020090fa180e49
FA-1D_006 20030090fa180e49
FA-4D_004 20030090fa180e49
FA-2D_006 20040090fa180e49
FA-2D_009 20040090fa180e49
FA-3D_005 20040090fa180e49
FA-1D_006 10000090fa180e48
FA-1D_011 10000090fa180e48
FA-2D_006 10000090fa180e48
FA-3D_005 10000090fa180e48
FA-4D_006 10000090fa180e48
FA-1D_004 20010090fa180e48
FA-2D_006 20010090fa180e48
FA-2D_011 20010090fa180e48
FA-3D_004 20010090fa180e48
FA-3D_006 20010090fa180e48
FA-4D_005 20010090fa180e48
FA-1D_006 20020090fa180e48
FA-2D_004 20020090fa180e48
FA-2D_010 20020090fa180e48
FA-3D_004 20020090fa180e48
FA-4D_004 20020090fa180e48
FA-3D_005 20030090fa180e48
FA-3D_007 20030090fa180e48
FA-1D_005 20040090fa180e48
```

***Would Result - With GNU awk :***

```
--------------------------
FA-1D_004 20010090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-1D_005 20040090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-1D_006 20020090fa180e49
          20030090fa180e49
          10000090fa180e48
          20020090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-1D_011 10000090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-2D_004 20010090fa180e49
          20020090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-2D_006 10000090fa180e49
          20040090fa180e49
          10000090fa180e48
          20010090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-2D_008 20010090fa180e49
--------------------------
FA-2D_009 20040090fa180e49
--------------------------
FA-2D_010 20020090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-2D_011 10000090fa180e49
          20010090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-3D_004 10000090fa180e49
          20010090fa180e49
          20010090fa180e48
          20020090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-3D_005 20040090fa180e49
          10000090fa180e48
          20030090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-3D_006 20010090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-3D_007 20030090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-4D_004 20020090fa180e49
          20030090fa180e49
          20020090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-4D_005 10000090fa180e49
          20010090fa180e48
--------------------------
FA-4D_006 10000090fa180e48
```